# "Bot is not valid. Errors: MsaAppId: MsaAppId is already in use

Tags: botframework, .net-core-2.2

I am getting this error now when I tried to deploy a new skill to my virtual Assistant bot

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
>   484cfdba-38bb-4d45-8358-9245aef97167. { "error": { "code":
>   "InvalidBotData", "message": "Bot is not valid. Errors: MsaAppId:
>   MsaAppId is already in use.. " } }

As per comments posted [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/264), one app id can only be related to one bot.

So does that mean for each of the skill that I want to add to my Virtual Assistant bot, I need to create new MSA App ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to have a separate MSA app (ID would be unique, password *could* be the same if you wish).

Each skill (along with the Virtual Assistant itself) is a bot framework ***bot***. Each bot is at the simplest, a `bot channels registration`. Each registration maps to an app and needs to be unique.